# Do future events influence the probability of past events?

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

This question came to mind when I was dealing with this question: A card from a pack of 52 cards is lost. From the remaining cards of the pack, two cards are drawn at random and are found to be clubs. Find the probability that the lost card is a club.

My query: The probability that a club is lost is $13/52$. The next event of taking two cards from this incomplete set of cards happens after one of the cards is lost. How can this affect a past event of losing a card from the pack?

Comment: http://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/index.php/Reannual_plant

Comment: Also, it may help to note that you are actually talking about two different probabilities: first one is if event will occur (a priory probability), and second is if event has actually occurred given some information (a posteriory probability).

Comment: I think @Boris 's answer makes much more sense than what others have told up to now.

Answer (score 4):

The event has not changed. Your information regarding the event has changed.

For instance, say you were interested if the Club Ace was lost.

Now if the two cards happen to have the Club Ace, would your estimate of the chances still be as before?

Basically, the probability is based on what information you have at hand.

Comment: It is raining and I am coming out of the building, I have no idea if it is raining outside or not, so for me it is as likely to get wet as it is likely that I stay dry. Looks bizarre to me.

Answer (score 1):

Let us extend your example. If we lose 13 cards, and after that open 52 - 13 cards and all of them are not clubs, what is the probability of all 13 lost cards to be clubs? It is clearly $1$.

Bayes theorem is not about affecting past events. It is about recalculation of probabilities when you have some more information. Probability of drawing two clubs after the card was lost depends on what card was lost. If the lost card is a club drawing two clubs after that becomes less probable than before. So, you can readjust your estimation of probability based on this information.

Comment: How the probability of an event is related to my information about the world? Does the probability of raining tomorrow changes if i think differently about it?

Comment: Sir, I know that loosing a card will influence the probability of taking the same type of card after the card has been lost but, how in the reverse sense. How can getting two clubs affect loosing a club in the past. I'm still not able to understand.

Comment: But we are not talking about sheer probability here. We are talking about estimation of probability given some additional information. You throw a dice, what is the probability that a result is six? $\frac{1}{6}$. But what if I tell you that result is divisible by $2$? Now you have some information. And there is only three elementary outcomes ($2$, $4$ and $6$) that suffices given information.  So now (with given information) probability of result being six is $\frac{1}{3}$.

Comment: Probability is never objective. Is tied to **lack** of information.

Answer (score 1):

There is a huge misconception in general about probability. It has nothing to do with future or past. It's the grade of certainty that subjectively you have about an event or proposition; pass, present or future.

For example a medical test gives a probability of someone having some decease Whis is a proposition about present. I have the decease or not.

Probability can change with time as my information changes.

There are many different probabilities for raining tomorrow but there is no absolute, objective probability of that.

Or looking thatmt in other way, objective probability is either 0 or 1

(Leave alone quantum mechanics)

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing correlation with causation.  Two variables are correlated when there is any (nontrivial) relation between them.  Two variables have a causal relation when a human can control one to influence the other.

Correlation is what mathematics and science deal with.  Causation is what engineers and designers deal with.

There is a correlation between the future event and the past event.  But you cannot "control" the future event in a way to change the past event.

Comment: But how do you relate it to probability? Isn't it that the probability of event $e$ is just a function of $e$? Well $e$ has happened and it is over.

Comment: Probability is not a function of an event.  Probability is a function of propositions.  Saying "the probability of event..." is actually inconsistent.  Everyone says it, and everyone is wrong.  That's why you never see probability in a formal logic:  if anyone ever created a formal calculus for probability, in order to be correct, it would have to differ from the modern approach so much that no one would intuitively know how to use it.